# Matplotlib text rendering with LaTeX with arbitrary string

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, latex, gtk3

Matplotlib is capable of parsing latex strings and displaying (to some extent) LaTeX math expressions. It also has a built in "math mode" which similarly displays nice-looking math expressions. To do this one places an *r* in front of the string, outside the quotes. An example of annotating a plot would be,

```
plt.xlabel(r'\textbf{time} (s)')
```

My understanding is that the *r* allows for proper escaping of special commands or characters like *\textbf* or *\alpha*.

How do I do this  when I'm not writing the string in my code? I'm reading a **Gtk.Entry** to get the string I want and I want to give that string to matplotlib to be interpreted as a LaTeX string. In the example above I would instead have,

```
string = Gtk.Entry.get_text()
plt.xlabel(r+string)              #how would I write this part?
```

Any help would be lovely.

Comment: The `r` tells python to _not_ treat the `'\'` as an escape in the string literal or you would have to write `\\textbf{time} (s)` where the first `'\'` escapes the second (or the string literal wolud be `'[tab]extbf{time} (s)'`).  If you have a string from Gtk it should 'just work'.

Comment: annoyingly backslash _also_ escapes the flavor of md that SO uses.

Comment: I don't understand your second comment. Could you elaborate? I tried using double backslash, i.e., *ax.text(0, 0.9,'\\textbf{hello}', transform=ax.transAxes, usetex=True)* but got a runtime error, '**RuntimeError: In select_charmap: Could not set the charmap**'.

EDIT: I also tried handing the Gtk.Entry.get_text() to ax.text() with the option *usetex=True* and got the same runtime error. I can give you the full trace if necessary.

Comment: Oh, SO=stack overflow, never mind, I understand your second comment now. I do, however, still have my runtime error. Any help would be great.

Comment: The runtime error disappears when I place a string inside of $$. If I do not include these I get the runtime error above. Is this expected and intentional behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so it turns out that the problem was that, like LaTeX, math needs to be in the math environment by bracketing the text with $insert math here$.

Answer (score 0):

As the tags indicates `Python-3.x` I think you could do something like:

```
plt.xlabel(mystring.encode('unicode_escape').decode('utf'))
```

being `mystring` the value returned by `Gtk.Entry.get_text()` and being `mystring` a `str` instance in Python3.